# Where to find coredll.lib in WinCE

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bluetooth, windows-ce, winsock2

I am writing a sample application in WindowsCE 6.0. I want to connect the handheld device to another bluetooth device and exchange data. I am following this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms881713.aspx). But when the sample code is compiled I am getting these errors

> 1>BlueToothTestDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   WSALookupServiceEnd referenced in function "public: void __cdecl
>   CBlueToothTestDlg::OnBnClickedFdButton(void)"
>   (?OnBnClickedFdButton@CBlueToothTestDlg@@QAAXXZ)
>
> 1>BlueToothTestDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   WSALookupServiceNextW referenced in function "public: void __cdecl
>   CBlueToothTestDlg::OnBnClickedFdButton(void)"
>   (?OnBnClickedFdButton@CBlueToothTestDlg@@QAAXXZ)
>
> 1>BlueToothTestDlg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   WSALookupServiceBeginW referenced in function "public: void __cdecl
>   CBlueToothTestDlg::OnBnClickedFdButton(void)"
>   (?OnBnClickedFdButton@CBlueToothTestDlg@@QAAXXZ) 1>FLEX7000_2450
>
> (ARMV4I)\Debug\BlueToothTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved
>   externals

I have included these headers

```
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2bth.h>
#include <bt_sdp.h>
#include <bthapi.h>
#include <bt_api.h>
#include <winioctl.h>
```

When searched I [found](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/compilation-bluetooth-program-gives-linking-error-wince-5-0-help-82460942.html) that it can be because the coredll.lib is missing. But I am not sure where to find it and how to include this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found solution. I added **Ws2.lib** in Linker Input flags under project properties and now the app builds.